# JUnit test case to cover multiple stream filter conditions - SonarQube code coverage

Tags: java, junit, sonarqube, code-coverage, test-coverage

Working on SonarQube code coverage & stuck with below conditional filter from stream. I need to write Junit such as both conditions will get covered and should cover this line as part of sonar. Quick help is appreciated. Let me know if you need more details on this. I am trying to mock below conditions in junit, but filtered line is not being covered. Sorry but cannot upload full code as per company policy, but please comment if you need more clarity on this or any references on internet.

```
private Optional<MainClass> mainMethod() {
        return classObject.stream()
                .filter(r -> r.salary() == 1000 || r.salary() == 2000)   //Need to cover both conditions as part of SonarQube code coverage
        .findAny();
    }
```

Tried to mock `classObject` with

1. `when(mockClassObject.salary()).thenReturn(1000)`  - Expecting to cover first condition.
2. ```
   when(mockClassObject.salary()).thenReturn(2000) - Expecting to cover second condition.
   ```
3. ```
   when(mockClassObject.salary()).thenReturn(10) - Uncovered condition
   ```

but it doesn't seems to be covering 3 conditions.

Comment: What’s the type of `classObject`? This code calls `stream()` on it, suggesting it is some kind of collection. You should test it once with an entry that has a salary of 1000, once with an entry that has a salary of 2000, and once where no entries have a salary of 1000 or 2000. You can’t cover all three cases in a single assertion, since the code will search through the stream for a matching entry and return as soon as one satisfies the filter condition. I would additionally test other cases (match at the start/end/middle of the stream, empty streams). Don’t only satisfy the coverage check.

Comment: If you can’t post your full code, it’s best to create a [mre] and post that.

Comment: For 3 conditions it's best to create 3 tests (or one parameterized test).